# Sorting a map of keys and values please to order a list in ES6 with Lodash (Keeping Firebase Key: UID)?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm currently trying to sort a list of employees in order of names but I'm having difficulty in such.

I'm using React-Native, with ES6, Lodash and firebase.

Firebase structure appears as:

[image: Firebase Employees Document Store Representation]

The state.employees structure appears as:

{"-KgMYnBrqXCIPqjs0n7x":{"name":"James","phone":"123766","shift":"Monday"},  "-KgRiK6qiJsoZ_HBXt7K":{"name":"Nick","phone":"123767","shift":"Tuesday"},"-KgRiM77VTOejvYPWPIp":{"name":"Henry","phone":"123","shift":"Thursday"},"-KgRiOaN14OeSjaYWb1O":{"name":"Charlie","phone":"5643","shift":"Saturday"}}

and continues with more employees each having a UID and then properties such as name, phone and shift.

Although I am able to order the list with _.orderBy provided by Lodash, it appears that when doing so the UID as the key provided by firebase is removed when applied say before _.map.

This is what I currently have which orders but the UID is removed, the _.map works fine keeping the UID with the properties but is unordered.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {    
    const sortedEmployees = _.orderBy(
        state.employees, 
        [employee => employee.name.toLowerCase()]
    );
    const employees = _.map(sortedEmployees, (val, uid) => {
        return { ...val, uid };
    });

    return { employees };
};
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Could you clarify how state.employees structure looks like with some data ? Is that like `[ { kgMYnBrqXCIPqjs0n7x: { name: 'James', phone: '123766', shift: 'Monday'} }, ....  ]`

Comment: Thanks @agent_hunt, I've added the representation of state.employees above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.orderBy(collection, [iteratees=[_.identity]], [orders])` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy

It seems when lodash maps over collection of type Object, it omits its key. 
One way to fix would be to convert the collection of object from firebase response to an array . Ex:

```
const arrWithKeys = Object.keys(state.employees).map((key) => {
    return {
      key,
      ...state.employees[key]
    }
});
```

and then use

```
const sortedEmployees = _.orderBy(
        arrWithKeys, 
        [employee => employee.name.toLowerCase()]
    );
```

You can also use firebase sorting in your firebase query

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your response @agent_hunt. I tried implementing it as suggested having the same structure as that of _.map but it then complained about TypeError: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" where it is not null nor undefined and actually matches the original _.map but this time ordered. 

To stop it complaining about, I added as a final thought the _.map again but this time taking the sortedEmployees and returning { ...val, uid} and it works. 

Couldn't get the firebase query to approach, as I had to order by child of child not knowing the key for each employee.

Comment: Here's what I implemented following your above arrWithKeys and sortedEmployees adding _.map as an after thought works

`const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const arrWithKeys = Object.keys(state.employees).map((uid) => {
        return {
            ...state.employees[uid],
            uid,
        };
    });

    const sortedEmployees = _.orderBy(
        arrWithKeys,
        [employee => employee.name.toLowerCase()],
    );

    const employees = _.map(sortedEmployees, (val, uid) => {
        return { ...val, uid };
    });
    
    return { employees };
};`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response @agent_hunt. I tried implementing it as suggested having the same structure as that of _.map but it then complained about TypeError: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" where it is not null nor undefined and actually matches the original _.map but this time ordered.

To stop it complaining about, I added as a final thought the _.map again but this time taking the sortedEmployees and returning { ...val, uid} and it works.

Couldn't get the firebase query approach to work, as I had to order by a child of a child (key) not knowing the key for each employee.

Here's what I implemented following your above arrWithKeys and sortedEmployees adding _.map as an after thought works

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const arrWithKeys = Object.keys(state.employees).map((uid) => {
        return {
            ...state.employees[uid],
            uid,
        };
    });

    const sortedEmployees = _.orderBy(
        arrWithKeys,
        [employee => employee.name.toLowerCase()],
    );

    const employees = _.map(sortedEmployees);

    return { employees };
};
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy